# Remove first two digit and change phonenumber format SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a tableA in which PhoneNumber column have values like 911234567891.
i want to remove the first two digits from the start i.e 1234567891 and then i want to change it to phone number format xxx-xxx-xxxx so the ending result will be 123-456-7891.
I have already done it using seprate Select and Update query like this:

```
SELECT
     [Phone Numbers]
    ,FORMAT([Phone Numbers],'###-###-####') AS [Formatted Phone]
    FROM tbl_sample


UPDATE tbl_sample
SET    [Phone Numbers] = SUBSTRING([Phone Numbers], 3, 8000) 
WHERE [Phone Numbers] LIKE '91%'
```

Is it possible to do it using single select query only so that there will be no need to update the data first?
Any kind of help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check the length of the value instead of 91%. What happens when the length is only 10 characters and the area code is something like 913?

Comment: If this will never be used for another region, then it is okay.  Though actually *changing* the data in the table makes the possible future addition of Asian, European, South American, etc. phone numbers very challenging.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it using `SUBSTRING` if the length of the column is always fixed.

```
UPDATE tbl_sample
SET [Phone Numbers] = SUBSTRING([Phone Numbers], 3, 3) + '-'+
                      SUBSTRING([Phone Numbers], 6, 3) + '-'+
                      SUBSTRING([Phone Numbers], 9, 4)
WHERE [Phone Numbers] LIKE '91%'
```

Using `FORMAT` if the column `[Phone Numbers]` is a numeric category datatype.

```
UPDATE tbl_sample
SET [Phone Numbers] = FORMAT([Phone Numbers]-910000000000,'###-###-####')
WHERE [Phone Numbers] LIKE '91%'
```

If you just need a `select`,

```
SELECT [Phone Numbers],
FORMAT([Phone Numbers]-910000000000,'###-###-####') formatted_number
--if [Phone Numbers] is varchar use
--FORMAT(cast([Phone Numbers] as numeric)-910000000000,'###-###-####')
FROM tbl_sample
WHERE [Phone Numbers] LIKE '91%'
```

Edit: To update a different table with the formatted phone number

```
UPDATE tb
SET tb.[Phone Numbers] = FORMAT(ta.[Phone Numbers]-910000000000,'###-###-####')
FROM tableA ta
JOIN tableB tb on ta.id = tb.id --change the join condition appropriately
WHERE tb.[Phone Numbers] LIKE '91%'
```

Comment: You are quite near what i really want to do here.
Actually I want to update my TableB from tableA on the basis of the phone numbers that are returned after they are formatted to '###-###-####'.

Comment: yup thats what i needed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
UPDATE tbl_sample
    SET [Phone Numbers] = FORMAT(SUBSTRING([Phone Numbers], 3, 8000), '###-###-####') 
    WHERE [Phone Numbers] LIKE '91%';
```

Or, alternatively,

```
select (case when [Phone Numbers] LIKE '91%'
             then FORMAT(CASt(SUBSTRING([Phone Numbers], 3, 8000) as bigint), '###-###-####') 
             else [Phone Numbers]
        end)
from tbl_sample;
```

Or, in SQL Server, you can add a computed column:

```
alter table tbl_sample
    add Formatted_Phone_Number as (
        case when [Phone Numbers] LIKE '91%'
             then FORMAT(CASt(SUBSTRING([Phone Numbers], 3, 8000) as bigint), '###-###-####') 
             else [Phone Numbers]
        end));
```

Comment: looks like the first argument to `FORMAT` can't be a `varchar` per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Comment: @vkp . . . Of course you are right.  I fixed the answer.